# Access NSManagedObject properties in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I'm getting NSManagedObjects from core data and trying to populate tableview. When i get the objects array i'm able to access and print the property. But when i try to access the same in tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath i'm getting nil value. Why is this happening?

[image]

```
{


import UIKit
```

class NotesView: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

```
//MARK:- IBOutlets
@IBOutlet weak var NotesTable: UITableView!
var notesArray = [Notes]()

//MARK:- ViewController Delegates
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    notesArray = Notes.getNotes()
    for value in notesArray{
        print(value.body!)
    }
    print(notesArray[0].body)
    NotesTable.delegate = self
    NotesTable.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
//MARK:- TabelView Delegate Methods
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return notesArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NotesTableCell")
    for value in notesArray{
        print("Value = \(value.body)")
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = (notesArray[indexPath.row]).body!

    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main",bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewNoteVC") as! NewNoteView
    vc.display = true
    vc.text = notesArray[indexPath.row].body!
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that all of your `Notes` instance have a `body` value? those error will be shown if you force nil value to be non-nil

Comment: Yes there are 2 values and those are printed properly. If there is no body value the error should come in viewdidload itself.

Comment: To help other people answer and help you, it is better if you post your code here instead of linked image.

Comment: Is the table view instance connected in Interface Builder? By the way, you can also connect delegate and datasource in IB rather than in code.

Comment: TableView is connected. If i print notesArray[0].body in viewDidLoad its printing fine, the same in tableView methods is printing nil.

Answer (score 0):

You shall confirm first the object at position [index.row] is not nil

Comment: yes in tableview method the Notes object is having all nil values, till viewDidAppear the values are not nil and printing properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found that NSManagedObjects lifetime is less i.e. we can't store them in an array or something and use it later. So i started using NSManagedSubClasses and using them instead.